# Heroku Django webapp getting error logs say gunicorn command not found but it is there

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to run a django app on heroku with postgresql but i'm getting
when i go to my app url i check the heroku logs --tail and see

`2018-08-27T10:37:19.086599+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-27T10:37:19.070449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-08-27T10:37:18.986150+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found`

i have a requirements.txt with gunicorn, the heroku python buildpack installed

i try maybe installing gunicorn remotely with 
`heroku run pip install -r requirements.txt`

but i get
`›   Error: remote requirements.txt not found in git remotes`

Comment: Check if `requirements.txt` is in root folder just like `manage.py`.

Comment: Also check if you added gunicorn to your installed apps. I made that mistake once.

Comment: it is in root floydya and ah i didn't know that was neccessary Disney

Comment: is adding  'gunicorn' to the settings.py installed apps the correct way?

Comment: ok i also then had the error of needing to allow heroku to allowed hosts but after that it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working with Django and saw this same exact error in `heroku logs --tail` a few minutes after I pushed updated to Heroku. Prior to the push to Heroku everything worked just fine.

To solve this problem,  first I made sure that the following files that worked previously remain unchanged with the push:

- requirements.txt
- Aptfile
- Procfile
- runtime
- wsgi

Since these files remained unchanged, I concluded that something beyond my knowledge was causing issues. So I went into the app's `Activity Feed` in Heroku, found the version that I knew worked and clicked on the `Roll back to here` link.

When that didn't work, per the recommendation of another user (whose comment I can't seem to find now), I removed all packages from the `requirements.txt` then pushed it up to Heroku so that all packages would be uninstalled in the app. Then I added back all packages to the `requirements.txt` and pushed it to Heroku. Now it works.